# Inserting a "date-time" into TIMESTAMP column -- "Incorrect datetime value"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, timestamp, date-format

I have a date-time data that comes in this format:

```
2016-02-10T12:00:00.000Z
```

I've created a MariaDb database and a column for that date of type `TIMESTAMP`

However, when inserting the data into the column, I'll get an exception:

```
Db error: Incorrect datetime value: 2016-02-10T12:00:00.000Z for column `my_db`.`my_table`.`dt_column`
```

I've tried to replace `Z` with `'+00:00'` -- to no avail, the error remained the same.

What's incorrect about it? Should I tweak the data type of my column somehow?

Or should I preprocess the value itself? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL/MariaDB are rather lame when it comes to standard date syntaxes.  Remove the `Z`.  (`REPLACE('...', 'Z', '')`)

The `T` may also cause trouble.  (`REPLACE('...', 'T', ' ')`)